# Rounding Issue in SQL compatibility level 130 vs 100

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-administration

I have been reached out by dev asking about rounding issue.

We are planning to migrate our database to SQL Server 2016 and during new SQL platform testing, we found that SQL Server 2016 is little off in rounding than expected.

This difference appears to be either the result of a change in the default rounding methodology when changing/set higher compatibility level.

--SQL Server 2016 database with Compatibility mode 130

```
declare @a float = -0.0051175 -- 7 digits
declare @b float = 0.0051175

select round(@a, 6), round(@b, 6)

Result
------------------------------------
-0.005117 , 0.005117
```

--SQL Server 2016 database with Compatibility mode 100

```
declare @a float = -0.0051175 -- 7 digits
declare @b float = 0.0051175

select round(@a, 6), round(@b, 6)

Result
-----------------------------------
-0.005118   , 0.005118
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: If you are really concerned about accurate data you should stop using float. It is NOT an exact datatype and round errors will happen. Use decimal instead and those rounding errors will no longer happen.

Comment: Compatibility level 110 is also `-0.005118, 0.005118`

Comment: thanks yeah, I just realized that. it works the way we expect until compatibility level 120 and then changes with 130.

Comment: There were major optimizer changes in 2016, so is not completely unexpected. The representation of the constant is the same under both compat levels and identical to what C# loads (`0x3F74F61672324C83`), so it's `ROUND` that's affected, whose exact algorithm is not documented. There are [documented changes](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4010261/) in FP handling, but this is not one of the documented changes (and trace flag 139 has no effect). Note that `ROUND(0.0051175000000000005e, 6)` is "correct" (with `0.0051175000000000005e` being the next `FLOAT`).

Comment: My advice would be to take this change as a given, investigate what parts of your database might run into trouble, and change them so they don't (preferable by switching to `DECIMAL` calculations where possible, or incorporating epsilon offsets, or in the worst case by using CLR functions that will not change their semantics across compat levels). The next release might break more, and even if MS devs should decide this is actually a bug in `ROUND` (which seems unlikely) they're not likely to revert the behavior for current releases.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that the `FLOAT` the constant converts to is ever so slightly less than `0.0051175` (so it's more like `0.00511749999..`) so in some sense `ROUND` is "correct". In another sense, it's not -- it all depends on how exactly you define the operation, which the documentation carefully fails to do.

Comment: Thanks All Dev is looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

Covered on my blog - https://justdaveinfo.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/sql-server-2016-upgrading-to-compatability-level-130trace-flag-139-and-additional-one-off-dbcc-checks/

"https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4010261/sql-server-2016-improvements-in-handling-some-data-types-and-uncommon-

When upgrading to SQL Server 2016 RTM CU3/SP1 and upgrading to database compatablity leve 130 there are additional DBCC checks which should be performed.

These are hidden behind Trace flag 139 which should be temporarily enabled as part of the process of changing database compability level to 130.

```
Enable trace flag 139 by running DBCC TRACEON(139, -1).
Run DBCC CHECKDB/TABLE..WITH EXTENDED_LOGICAL_CHECKS to validate persisted structures
Run DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS commands (if rows are affected the associated where clause to identify the row will be returned).
Disable trace flag 139 by running DBCC TRACEOFF(139, -1)
Change the database compatibility level to 130.
REBUILD any structures that you identified in step 1.
```

There are impovements to expression evaluation in database level 130 and this affects persisted structures

```
Check constraints
Persisted Computed columns
Indexes using computing columns whether as part of the key or as included columns
Filtered indexes
Indexed views
```

Upgrade to compatability level 130 BEFORE attempting to fix issues so the new expression evaluation logic is used for the fixed.

```
Check constraints – change data or drop/recreate constraint with new expression
Persisted Computed columns – Update a column referenced by the computed column to the same value to force recalcuation of the computed column
Index/filtered index/indexed views – Either A) Put db in single user mode and run DBCC CHECKTABLE with REPAIR_REBUILD B) ALTER INDEX…REBUILD and if supported in your edition of sql server consider adding the WITH (ONLINE=ON) clause.
```

NOTE: There are some queries in the Appendix C/D of the article above which can be used to help identify affected objects."